# Change background-image of DIV depending on LI click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a website to showcase an app and want to allow users to click through an iPhone mockup to view various features of the app.

I have an iPhone overlay, housed as a background-image, (.iphone) and a screen grab, also housed as a background-image, (.screen) on the page, but want users to be able to dictate what screengrab is shown by clicking specific buttons.

I'm not familiar with JQuery myself but have been told that that would be a possible solution to this. How would I achieve this? My code is...

```
<div class="iphone"></div>
<div class="screen"></div>

<ul>
<li class="screenshots">Screen 1</li>
<li class="screenshots">Screen 2</li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I've found an example of something similar. Here it is...[link](http://www.potionfactory.com/thehitlist/iphone/). Click a thumbnail and it shows on the iPhone.

Comment: you mention screenshot in your post but i don't see any image tags in your code. is there really an image tag in place of `Screen 1`?

Comment: The screenshot will be housed as a background image on the "screen" class

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking.  Are you asking how to write the click handler to process the click and change background images?  Or are you asking how to make the screen shot go inside of the iphone image like in your example?

Comment: Would it not be the same thing? I have an iPhone overlay image, that is a background image in the class "iphone". I have a placeholder image already in the iPhone, that is "screen" and has a background-image" applied to it. What I want is, when the Screen 1 or 2 buttons are pressed, the image changes in the "screen" class, to a new screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to explain as best I can. Not easy.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="iphone"></div>
<div class="screen"></div>
<ul>
<li class="screenshots"><a href="#" id="scr1">Screen 1</a></li>
<li class="screenshots"><a href="#" id="scr2">Screen 2</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
$('.screenshots a').click(function(){
    switch($(this).attr('id')){
        case 'src1':
            $('.iphone').css('background-image','url("image1.png")');
        break;
        case 'src2':
            $('.iphone').css('background-image','url("image2.png")');
        break;
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: It seems like it would be better to use only a single click handler that is smart enough to adapt to which one was clicked on rather than multiple individually coded click handlers (think DRY).

Comment: @Mark Linus, I worded my question very badly. Tried revising it to make is more easier to understand.

Comment: So could you explain it better? I'm a little bit confused

Comment: @Mark Linus, I've revised my original post. Still no better?

Comment: @MarkLinus I'm trying to do something like [this](http://www.potionfactory.com/thehitlist/iphone/) Click a thumbnail and it shows on iPhone.

Comment: @MarkLinus I can't click on <li>. Do they need <a>?

Comment: Yes, you can also isnert an `a` tag inside the `li` element. Just change the events to it

Comment: @MarkLinus `<li><a class="screenshots" id="scr1">Screen 1</a></li>`? What should `href` be?

Comment: Could you please tell me what happened?

Comment: @MarkLinus Nothing happened. I clicked the link but the image did not change.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably set it up as follows:

```
<div class="fullsize">
  <div class="iphone"></div>
  <div class="screen"></div>
<div>

<ul class="screenshots">
  <li class="iphone" id="scr1">Screen 1</li>
  <li class="screen" id="scr2">Screen 2</li>
</ul>
<script>
$('.screenshots li').click(function() {
  $('.fullsize div').hasClass($(this).attr('class')).css('background-image', 'imgurl'));
});
</script>
```

Comment: I worded my question very badly. Tried revising it to make is more easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').click(function(){
   $('div').css("background-image", "image/url/here.ext");
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

Semantically speaking, your markup should look like:

```
<div class="screenshot" id="iphone"></div>
<div class="screenshot" id="screen"></div>

<ul id="screenshot-nav">
<li><a href="#iphone">Screen 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#screen">Screen 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

It's more appropriate to use actual links instead of adding a click event to an `li`. Besides, doing it this way allows the functionality to work even without javascript, as at the very least, the user will simply be "jumped" to the right screenshot.

With that in place, the following jQuery should work:

```
$('#screenshot-nav a').click(function(){
    $('.screenshot').hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).show();
});
```

However, since you're making this for an iPhone, you should probably look into jQuery Mobile, instead, and particularly the `touch` event handler, instead of `click`.

Comment: I worded my question very badly. Tried revising it to make is more easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a single jQuery click handler that can set the desired image background for each one:

```
<div class="iphone"></div>
<div class="screen"></div>
<ul>
<li class="screenshots" data-backgroundurl="url1.jpg">Screen 1</li>
<li class="screenshots" data-backgroundurl="url2.jpg">Screen 2</li>
</ul>
<script>
$('.screenshots').click(function(){
    $('.screen').css('background-image', $(this).data("backgroundurl"));
});
</script>
```

Comment: I worded my question very badly. Tried revising it to make is more easier to understand.